# How to get user profile using  gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I know that this is very basic and silly question, but as I am a starter and looking for example from morning to use gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git".

Please provide me with example using this gem.

Because i see here https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/tree/master/lib/linked_in that the client class only have initialize not having new method also

```
 def initialize(ctoken=LinkedIn.token, csecret=LinkedIn.secret, options={})
```

what is option here what to pass there? this also is available in client class.

Comment: for people who downvote this question. i have been trying to get working sample but could not get, I would suggest that instead of downvoting please provide some help.

Comment: Did you have a look at the readme? This seems pretty easy, also I did not try. What did you try? What kind of errors did occur?

Comment: if you could see this readme, it is okay for deskop that too even ther is no client.profile method now. when i try to us this code it gives me only nokgori type of output which now replaced, and if you could see client class there we have only initialize method there is no new method. anyway thanks for the reply also somebody downvoted so i will not be hencforth able to ask question, thanks you guys.

Comment: Mhh I installed the linkedin gem and it seems to work, but I can not test because I do not have linkedin. The `.profile` method exists for me. Could you post some code? Did you check the link on the readme to the rails project?

Comment: client = Linkedin::client.initialize(etc), can you access this method?

Comment: About the downvote: I think it is the way you ask your questions. You do not provide your own code. What do you expect? That we write all the code for you? No gonna happen. We want to guide you, point you the direction but for this you need to show some effort.

Comment: Where did you get the `.initalize` method from? You should use `.new` and please post some more code! Edit your question and add some more code, it is not helpful with just one line of code.

Comment: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/tree/master/lib/linked_in, Please find client class there you can find that

Comment: Yeah but stick to the readme. Ruby maps the `initalize` method to be called via `Class.new`. So `Linkedin::Client.new(params)` works for me.

Comment: it also works for me, how to get profile from the client? client.profile returns  #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x253b5ac "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x253b57c name="last-name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::
Text:0x253b3b4 "Raj S">]>, 
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x253b2dc "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x253b2ac name="headline" children=[#<Nokogiri::X
ML::Text:0x253b0e4 "Senior Software Engineer at AB Innovative Software Pvt. Ltd">]>, 
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x253b00c "\n  ">, etc.how to get value from there because i see that now the results are stored in map using recent gem. can you help me?

Comment: @klump could you give me a answer if not please upvote so that i will be able to ask questions and it is very useful for me to learn

Comment: You should be able to ask questions again but please provide some more information and show that you made some effort, like posting your code without people asking for it. Also try to have a little more patience.

Comment: undefined method `[]' for #<LinkedIn::Profile:0x443e590> sorry this is the error i get.

Comment: what is the response you get of `client.profile`? It is not an array... I will update my answer

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172841/how-to-get-logged-in-users-complete-profile-information-using-gem-linkedin  Press submit twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by adding:

```
client.profile(:fields => [:positions]).positions
```

This would then allow me to access specific positions or fields without going into the raw xml, just using the methods in the gem. The gem works nicely once I get the format...

Answer (score 1):

The call `client.profile` returns an array of profile information.

```
profile = client.profile

profile.positions # this should return the postions...
# maybe there is a function for each field like
profile.lastname
```

I am mostly guessing, since you did not provide much information and I dont have linkedin so I could try myself. Hope this is helpful.