# How to get logged in user's complete profile information using gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am using `gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"`

when i create client and get profile i get the following values

```
headline:   url: last_name: first_name:summary
```

my question is how to get user's

```
picture-url,public_profile_url: location: country: school_name: degree: field_of_study: start_date: end_date:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use picture_url like follows

client.profile(:fields => [:headline, :first_name, :last_name, :picture_url,:educations, :positions])client.profile(:fields => [:headline, :first_name, :last_name, :picture_url,:educations, :positions])

Answer (score 0):

For a list of all the fields you can use see the documentation at LinkedIn https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

```
#Gemfile
gem 'linkedin-oauth2', '~> 1.0.0'

# Other file
api = LinkedIn::API.new(linkedin.token)
profile = api.profile(
  fields: [
      :headline,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :email_address,
      :phone_numbers,
      :im_accounts,
      :industry,
      :main_address,
      :primary_twitter_account,
      :picture_url,
      :public_profile_url,
      :positions
    ]
  )
```